# Unit Tests Not Showing in Test View VS2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, resharper

So I have these unit tests in Visual Studio 2010, but they don't show up in Test View.  They show up in ReSharper, but I really want to see them in Test View too.  I've tried rebuilding, doing a full build, unchecking 'Disable background discovery of test methods', I've even tried disabling Unit Testing in ReSharper, but to no avail.  Any ideas?

Comment: What testing framework are you using?

Comment: @dtryon The framework I'm using is C#

Comment: @LillyRose C# is the programming language you are using, the testing framework would be NUnit or MSTest, etc. Visual Studio may only be able to show MSTests in Test View.

Comment: @PiersMyers Oh I believe it's MSTest

Comment: Seems like a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273174/visual-studio-2008-test-view-panel-not-showing-all-tests